# How many 15 digit long strings are there made up of the digits 0, 1, 2 or 3 such that there are 8 zeroes in 3 groups?

Tags: combinatorics

How many 15 digit long strings are there made up of the digits 0, 1, 2 or 3 such that there are 8 zeroes in 3 groups? For example, 123000100012003 is a valid string since there are three groups of zeroes.

For the zeroes, I used stars and bars to arrange the zeroes

${8 + 2 \choose 2}$

For the other digits,

$\frac{3^7}{7!}$

And then I thought that there are two ways to arrange the three groups of zeroes and three filler groups.

Zeroes - filler - zeroes - filler - zeroes - filler
or
filler- zeroes - filler - zeroes- filler -zeroes

So my final answer is 
${8 + 2 \choose 2} * 
\frac{3^7}{7!} * 2$

Can someone verify my answer/correct my work?

Comment: But your example string is NOT of length 15.

Comment: What's wrong with zeroes-filler-zeroes-filler-zeroes?   Or filler-zeroes-filler-zeroes-filler-zeroes-filler?  And how are you coping with the fact that you have to apportion the filler?  After all $01^6010^6$ is not the same as $01^201^50^6$, say.  Also, I don't understand where the $7!$ is coming from.

Comment: Your final answer will reduce to a rational number with a denominator divisible by $7$, so it can't represent the number of arrangements of anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eight $0$'s can be split into three groups in ${7\choose2}=21$ ways. The three groups of $0$'s can be inserted among seven nonzeros in ${8\choose3}=56$ ways. The seven nonzeros can be assigned values $1$, $2$ or $3$ in $3^7=2187$ ways, for a grand total of

$${7\choose2}{8\choose3}3^7=21\cdot56\cdot2187=2{,}571{,}912$$

fifteen-digit strings.

Comment: I redid the problem and got 8C3 in lieu of 10C3 as there are two gaps that must be at least one digit of length.                                          _ zeroes _ zeroes _ zeroes _

Comment: @StackStack9, yes, you are quite right! I've fixed my answer. Thank you for alerting me to my mistake.